# How to go back to previous frame that was invisible

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am very new to Java Swing and I am working on a login frame with swing that works like this.

After I login successfully in a frame, another new frame is opened while the login frame goes to invisible.

What I am trying to do is that when i close the another frame (after login frame) I want the previous login frame to show again from invisible to visible. please let me know how to do this..:)

Comment: The short answer would be, don't. Take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) for more detail. The longer answer would be to use a CardLayout which would allow you to switch between views on a single window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your previous frame is `myPreviousFrame`

just write `myPreviousFrame.setVisible(true);` when you want to make visible.

Example:

```
currentFrame.dispose();
myPreviousFrame.setVisible(true);
```

**Note:** if you write code `System.exit(0)` it will close (terminate) your application. When your application goes terminate you can not make login frame as visible. You need to restart your application.  So you need to write `dispose()`.

**UPDATED:**

I suppose you have a method `exitForm()` which invokes when you click the **Close (X)**.

Example:

```
private void exitForm(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                          
     //System.exit(0); which was used 
     // to fullfill your requirement you need to write below code
     this.dispose();// here [this] keyword means your current frame
     //OR simply you can use this.setVisible(false); instead of this.dispose();
     myPreviousFrame.setVisible(true); // this will displays your login frame
}
```

Comment: I know how to make it visible. But how can I implement the code that runs when I close the current frame please?

Comment: what should i do if i want your two line codes to run when i click the close (x) button on the top of frame please?

Comment: When you click the close (x), this is executing System.exit(0). This means your application terminated. So your login frame is not displaying. You need to replace System.exit(0) by like I suggested code. If you did not get idea where to place code like I suggested. Please show your code. Then I will tell you. I updated my answer see...

Answer (score 1):

u may try like this:

```
public class jFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame{
  // ur code
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jFrame2 f2 = new jFrame2(this);
    f2.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
  }
}

public class jFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame{
  // ur code
  private JFrame frame;

  public jFrame2(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
  }

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
    this.dispose();
  }

  // so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i am just  considering two frames and at present you are at second frame and wanna go back to first frame.

```
public class previous_action implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t){
        Movieticket m;
        m=new Movieticket();
        m.display();
    }
}
```

Here previous action is a class  which will take you back to previous frame.Button frame is a class which sets frame where we are at present.Movie ticket is a public class  containing display function which sets frame when the application started that is the first frame.
when the button is clicked it will take you to previous frame.